# How to find a button with "value" in html page (Webbrowser - Delphi)

Tags: html, delphi, browser

i have a html page that it have 3 forms with 3 submit buttons . buttons have no name but they have value :

```
<input type="submit" VALUE="Login">
```

How can i find this button with its value and **click on it** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  ovElements: OleVariant; 
  i: Integer; 
begin 
  ovElements := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.forms.item(0).elements; 
  for i := 0 to (ovElements.Length - 1) do
    if (ovElements.item(i).tagName = 'INPUT') and
      (ovElements.item(i).type = 'SUBMIT') and
  (ovElements.item(i).Value = 'Login') then
      ovElements.item(i).Click; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use in this case my Procedure WB_send_Click_by_Value:

```
procedure WB_send_Click_by_Value(WB: TWebbrowser;form_nr:nativeint;tag,typ,val: string);
var ovElements: OleVariant;
i: Integer;
begin
  ovElements := WB.OleObject.Document.forms.item(form_nr).elements;
  for i := 0 to (ovElements.Length - 1) do
    begin
      if AnsiSameText(ovElements.item(i).tagName,tag) and
         AnsiSameText(ovElements.item(i).type,typ) and
         AnsiSameText(ovElements.item(i).value,val) then
         ovElements.item(i).Click;
    end;
end;
```

I use this Procedure for Buttons in WebPage Formular 1 like:

```
WB_send_Click_by_Value(Webbrowser1,0,'input','submit','ok');
```

or e.g. for RadioButtons in Form 2 like:

```
WB_send_Click_by_Value(Webbrowser1,1,'input','radio','dns');
```