# Pressing Buttons on a web page via Delphi

Tags: delphi, button, twebbrowser

Ex1: [WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('ID HERE').Click;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593494/programmaticaly-click-on-a-link-in-webbrowser-using-dom-delphi-7)

Ex2: [< input type="submit" VALUE="Login" >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651054/how-to-find-a-button-with-value-in-html-page-webbrowser-delphi)

The above two examples are for pressing buttons on web pages via Delphi. Ex2 works well on various web sites but not all. Is this because Ex2 only works on HTML buttons? I tried Ex1 but some code is missing, when I try it, I get a message saying 'Object or class type required'. Also Ex1 has no example code, can anyone fill me in on why I get this message and put some code up for Ex1 please.

Comment: Post code on how are you using this. error of `Object or class type required` maybe due not having a variable of type `X` but hard to see what is happening without your code.

Comment: probably there si no element by given id or such.
You should debug it with the basic "divide and conquer" principle. Set several variable and split one line into several separate statements. `var1 := WebBrowser.OleObject; var2:= var1.Document; var3 := var2.GetElementByID('ID HERE'); var3.Click` then see which one fails.

Comment: Hi Arioch, thanks for the help, the problem was a typing mistake. I had 'WebBrowser' instead of 'WebBrowser1'. And your solution help me figure this out. But I may still need help on this later on. Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: When u address someone at SO - use twitter convention `@name`
You - being the one asking the question - would be notified of comments and answers. 
But i was not notified of your comment and only saw it by mere luck.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I got this code from: MrBaseball34 at [delphipages](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-118008.html)
It didn't work initially because I wrote 'WebBrowser' instead of 'WebBrowser1'. But it works perfectly.
Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
var  
x: integer;  
thelink: OleVariant; 

begin  
thelink:= WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.tags('A');  
if thelink.Length > 0 then  
  begin  
  for x := 0 to thelink.Length-1 do  
    begin  
    if Pos('put id string here', thelink.Item(x).id) > 0 then
      begin  
        thelink.Item(x).click;  
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with TWebBrowser, and COM/ActiveX objects in general, it's really handy to know the difference between late binding and early binding. If you use OleVariant variables, have them refer to 'live' object, and use the dot operator (`.`) to invoke methods and properties, they get resolved at run-time. They are *late  bound* as opposed to *early binding* where you would use specific interfaces.

Include unit `MSHTML` in the uses clause, and then use `IHTMLDocument3(WebBrowser1.Document)`, and the different interfaces defined by `MSHTML`, such as `IHTMLElement`and `IHTMLAnchorElement`. You will find that you also get code completion up to some point, but also that you might need an extra cast between things like `IHTMLElement` and `IHTMLElement2` with the `as`operator.

Answer (score 0):

There may be any kind of error. Like misspelled ID or wrong datatype  missing interface you hope to use, or lacking some item and returning `nil` instead.

Problem with long lines like `WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('ID HERE').Click;` is that you can hardly tell in which place the error occured. And sometimes it is not easy to check intermediate values and its properties. There are a lot of innate expectations coded in such long lines, and you can hardly detect which one was failed.

When you meet errors in such long lines, you'd better split them at tiny action items - the ol' good *divide and conquer* principle. Declare few variables and split this long  complex line into multiple simplistic ones.

```
var0 := WebBrowser;
var1 := var0.OleObject; 
var2 := var1.Document; 
var3 := var2.GetElementByID('ID HERE'); 
var3.Click;
```

Tracing this, executing one line a time, you can check which values and data types would be issued at each traversing step.